# Post to facebook wall after user adding facebook app to their facebook page

Tags: facebook

Do we have permission to post to a facebook page wall after their admin add our facebook app to their facebook page? Is that posible?

Comment: Nope, That's not possible unless you ask for `publish_stream` permissions.

Answer (score 2):

In order to publish anything you must have the **publish_stream** permission.